# How to set a not equal to a firestore query

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this query

```
         querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('sellerPost')
             .where("expireTime" , isGreaterThan: DateTime.now())
             .where("category", isEqualTo: _selectedCategory)
             .where("tags",arrayContains:_selectedTag )
             .orderBy('expireTime',descending: true)
             .limit(10)
             .getDocuments();
```

I would like to query documents with given categories and tags as specified in the where clause, but in. a situation where the user has not selected a tag or category yet, i would like to query everything.

E.g in my mind i though this would work

```
         querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('sellerPost')
             .where("expireTime" , isGreaterThan: DateTime.now())
             .where("category", isEqualTo: "*")
             .where("tags",arrayContains:"*" )
             .orderBy('expireTime',descending: true)
             .limit(10)
             .getDocuments();
```

Is there a way to query with wild cards this way?

Comment: in that case, you can simply omit the where conditions on `category` and `tags`. 
 
- use `where()` to query for all of the documents that meet a certain condition. Here, you don't have any condition on `category` and `tags`.

Comment: Yeah, i had to use an if to check if i have to use the where clause